# Is there bootstrap to automatically hide some components in different media screens?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm really annoyed with styling responsiveness and i was wondering if someone knows a bootstrap class that will automatically hide any component in medium and small screen, by all components i mean like a heading, paragraph, button and many more

Comment: Someone please help me out ill do appreciate alot

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses the following class name to determine the display property of elements.

```
.d-{breakpoint}-{value}
```

So for your example, hiding elements on small & medium screens will look like the following:

```
.d-none .d-lg-block
```

The first class `d-none` will hide elements on all screen sizes, so you need to specify a different display property for the larger screens, `d-lg-block` for example.

Please see the [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/) for further information

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what bootstrap version you are using. Any way this is how it done by bootstrap 3.x and 4.x.

From [Bootstrap 3.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) Documentation

This is an example that hidden from Extra small devices, Small devices and Medium devices

```
<div class="visible-lg-block">
  <h1>This is a heading text</h1>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

From [Bootstrap 4.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) Documentation

```
<!-- Visible only on lg --> 
<div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">
  <h1>This is a heading text</h1>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use these class names to hide any components

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcdrX.png)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).